# Establish resource manager context to use smart card reader

Tags: c++, windows-10, smartcard, winscard

I'm developing a `c++` application, using Visual Studio 2017.

I'm using the windows library [winscard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winscard/).
I'm starting with a simple project where i'm calling the function `SCardEstablishContext` as the first step needed to read a smart card.

The snippet of code i'm using is the following:

```cpp
LONG resContext = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM, NULL, NULL, &hSC);
if (resContext != SCARD_S_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Failed\n");
    printf("Error %X\n", resContext);
}
```

What i know is that this function use the windows service called "Smart Card" to get the scope within which database operations are performed (read/write cards).

Unfortunately this simple application works (i.e. return the `SCARD_S_SUCCESS` code) only in windows 7 environment. In all the windows 10 systems that i tested the return code is always `0x8010001DL` that is associated to the define `SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE` that assert:

> The Smart Card Resource Manager is not running.

On windows 7 systems the program works without admin privileges, on windows 10 systems i've tried with admin privileges too but the error is the same.

In every windows 10 system that i tested i manually started the service "Smart Card" before testing my program and checked that it still running while testing.

In both windows 7 and windows 10 systems i don't have a smart card reader connected.

The `winscard.lib` file i use come with `Microsoft Windows SDK` version `10.0.17763.0`

There's something extra to do to get it works with windows 10?

Comment: Smart Card Subsystem (and Resource Manger) must work "out of the box". Try to install some smart card drivers that present virtual slots to the system. For example this [one](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO27164.html)

Comment: Are you working via RDP?

Comment: @Alexander thanks to point that out, i was! I've tried my program on the device directly and now the function returns `SCARD_S_SUCCESS`, but why this behaviour? I'm still unable to get it work on win10 pc without a smart card connected. Installing that smart card driver didn't help. Maybe connecting a readed can resolve (i don't have one atm)?

Comment: I have a virtual token that can be "inserted" an then will be visible through Smart Card Resource Manger. I can share it with you, but do not see private way to communicate.

Comment: @Alexander thank you, but on next week i'll have an usb card reader and i'll see. The important part was to communicate with the reader on the tablet and i've achieved it. Please add an answer so i can assign the bounty.

Comment: How is your progress?

Comment: @Alexander With the card reader connected all is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smart Card Subsystem (and Resource Manger) must work "out of the box".

Try to install some smart card drivers that present virtual slots to the system.
For example this [one](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO27164.html).

Are you working via RDP?

Comment: I answered "yes" to the RDP question. I logged into the computer directly, and magic: I see the smart card reader. I guess it's a security feature so you don't share your smartcard with the world.

Answer (score 0):

As it said in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardestablishcontext)

> The calling application must have appropriate access permissions for
>   any database actions.

It means that you should run the program with admin privileges.

Comment: Yes, i didn't mention in my question but i tried with admin privileges too, but the result is the same.